# What is the degree of the pull back of a line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^2$, and let $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ be homogeneous coordinates on $X$. Consider a map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^1\longrightarrow X$, given by $\phi(x_1,x_2)=(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2)$, where $(x_1,x_2)$ are coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then the image is the conic in $\mathbb{P^2}$, given by $V(y_2^2-y_1y_3)$. And $i^*\mathcal{O}_X(1)=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$, and therefore has degree 2.

Can we same something analogous for every curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$? That is is can we identify it as a the image of a morphism under $\mathbb{P}^1$, and hence define the degree of $i^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ as the degree of the pulled back line bundle in $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: What is your definition of degree? Some people may define degree as $\deg(i^\ast\mathcal{O}(1))$.

Comment: Yes I would like to know the $deg(\mathcal{O}_C(1))= deg(i^*\mathcal{O}_X(1))$

Comment: How else can one define degree? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at Riemann-Roch?

Comment: Thanks Hoot, I would like to know how the pull back affects the degree? How do I use the Riemann roch? I don't know the gebus, I don't know $h^O$ and $h^1$?

Comment: Well it depends on your definition of degree, which you haven't given. For me the degree of a curve embedded in projective space would be the coefficient of $m$ in the Hilbert polynomial $p_C(m)$. For $m$ large enough (so $h^1$ vanishes) Riemann-Roch tells you everything.

Comment: Thanks @Hoot, I will frame the question better and post it.